# Unable to create React project using create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

So I'm trying to learn React, followed the instruction on https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html. Specifically, I'm using Create React App, and happened to bump into an error:

```
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test-react@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

From what I'm seeing here, the Testing library required that the installed React version be less than 18.0.0, but Create React App just automatically install the latest React version, leading to the error.

How do I resolve this? As said earlier, I'm a complete newbie, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until this is fixed for now you can delete the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`.

Next, open `package.json` and change `"react": "^18.0.0"` & `"react-dom": "^18.0.0"` to an earlier version e.g. `"react": "^17.0.2"` & `"react-dom": "^17.0.2"`.

Finally, can run `npm install`

Comment: Until this is fixed for now you can delete the "node_modules" folder and "package-lock.json". Next, open "package.json" and change "react": "^18.0.0" & "react-dom": "^18.0.0" to an earlier version e.g. "react": "^17.0.2" & "react-dom": "^17.0.2". Finally, can run "npm install".

Share
Edit
Follow
answered 1 hour ago
user avatar
Gavriel

Comment: Thank you. I guess that would have to do for now. Hopefully this issue would get resolved soon.

Comment: You have to enter the app folder BEFORE running `npm install`, (`cd my-app`).

Comment: I get a similar error. I changed my react and react-dom versions in my package.json from 17.0.2 to ^17.0.2 and indeed that resolved the error! @liam, are you saying this is a known issue? If so, do you know have a link to where it was reported?

Comment: @noob, you should consider accepting this answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: @Woodchuck  The problem has now been fixed, https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12279